# How to rotate a single view when iPad rotate

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, rotation

I work on an app on iPad with iOS 7. The main UIView (viewA) of this app is by construction always landscape. Inside the main view there is another small UIView (viewB). Both are controlled by the same mainViewController, that has this method

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
 }
```

Starting with iPad in landscape orientation, when I rotate the iPad in the portrait position, viewA and view B remains as they are. All right.

Now I want to make a change. To be precise, I want that, when iPad rotate from landscape to portrait, viewA remains as before, but viewB rotate automatically. How can I do? Have I to make a separate ViewController for viewB?

Thank you.

Comment: try to receive the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`, and handle the situation there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend/inherit the ViewController and override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method to return the proper orientation for view B

Example ViewControllerB.h:

```
@interface ViewControllerB : ViewControllerA {
}
```

ViewControllerB.m:

```
@implementation ViewControllerB

  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return true;
  }
@end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "extend the view controller?"

Comment: I have added some example code in my answer. Hope that helps.